Failing the Angular tests
I am trying to run the basic angular test that angular makes when creating a component, but they keep on failing, and i cannot find why or how to fix it.
These are the tests i am trying to run:
  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });


  it(`should have the 'FlinkRegi' title`, () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('FlinkRegi');
  });

  it('should render title', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h1')?.textContent).toContain('Hello, FlinkRegi');
  });

My full App.component.spec.ts:
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { RouterOutlet, RouterLink } from '@angular/router';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AppComponent,          // Import the standalone component directly
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatListModule,
        RouterOutlet,
        RouterLink
      ],
      providers: [
        provideAnimations(),
        provideRouter([]),    // Provide router with empty routes if not required
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });


  it(`should have the 'FlinkRegi' title`, () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('FlinkRegi');
  });

  it('should render title', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h1')?.textContent).toContain('Hello, FlinkRegi');
  });
});

App.component.ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet, RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, MatSidenavModule, MatListModule, RouterLink, provideAnimations()],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'FlinkRegi';
}


The errors i get:
AppComponent > should render title
Error: The "[object Object]" type, imported from "AppComponent", must be a standalone component / directive / pipe or an NgModule. Did you forget to add the required @Component / @Directive / @Pipe or @NgModule annotation?
AppComponent > should create the app
Error: The "[object Object]" type, imported from "AppComponent", must be a standalone component / directive / pipe or an NgModule. Did you forget to add the required @Component / @Directive / @Pipe or @NgModule annotation?
AppComponent > should have the 'FlinkRegi' title
Error: The "[object Object]" type, imported from "AppComponent", must be a standalone component / directive / pipe or an NgModule. Did you forget to add the required @Component / @Directive / @Pipe or @NgModule annotation?
I have no idea what the problem can be. i have no idea what the [object Object] is refering to, and i ried nearly any solution i could find.

You added provideAnimations() in your AppComponent imports. It seems to me that's the cause of your problem, because if I remove it in my reproduction, all tests pass.

Thank you! Removing fixed it for me as well.
